# vba -How to place a chart below/down a different location when there exists a chart at the current location

Tags: excel, vba

I select a range for the chart to create. When created I place at a different sheet called "charts". I first check the existence of this sheet-"charts" and then place it in  location. But what I want to achieve is if there exists a chart in that location already say I1 then I want the new chart that I created to go to I16. If that also has a chart then it should move to location I31 until it finds an empty spot.

```
  Dim blnFound As Boolean
blnFound = False
 '
 '
 ActiveChart.Parent.Cut

    End With
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
      If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "Charts" Then
       Sheets("Charts").Select
        Range("I1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        blnFound = True
        Exit For
        End If

        Next i
    If blnFound = False Then
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Charts"
    Sheets("Charts").Select
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
```

[image]
The above image shows how the charts are overlaping. 
I am using

```
  .Parent.Cut
```

and then pasting as in the code
 how do I achieve that in vba code?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to recursively call the same procedure that checks if a chart exists in your range and move the range down before checking again.

This code will check if a chart already covers the exact same range as the one you're trying to place.  If the second chart overlaps the first then it will happily create the new chart, only if both charts are trying to cover the *exact same range* will it try and move the new chart down.

**Note** - this sample code only creates the chart container, not the chart itself.
Any code to create the `chart` within the `chartobject` would go after the `ChartObjects.Add` line.

```
Sub Test()

    Add_Chart Sheet1.Range("C2:F5")

End Sub

Public Sub Add_Chart(Target As Range)

    Dim oCht As ChartObject 'The chart container.
    Dim bExists As Boolean  'Will be False when first created.

    'Look at each chart container on the sheet.
    For Each oCht In Target.Parent.ChartObjects
        If oCht.TopLeftCell.Address = Target.Cells(1, 1).Address And _
           oCht.BottomRightCell.Address = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count + 1, Target.Columns.Count + 1).Address Then
                bExists = True 'The chart does exist.
                Exit For 'No need to keep searching.
        End If
    Next oCht

    If bExists Then
        'Call this procedure again, but move the Target range down.
        Add_Chart Target.Offset(oCht.BottomRightCell.Row - oCht.TopLeftCell.Row)
    Else
        Target.Parent.ChartObjects.Add _
            Target.Left, Target.Top, Target.Width, Target.Height
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I run my code as it is It does shift the chart one cell row below and about same row width below shift in column(not one column though). Tried to add this code and use Add_Chart Selection.Paste. but did not have any effect. May be because it is not exact overlap

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple and position the next chart just under the previous one by looking at its top and height properties. Assuming you've assigned your worksheet to a variable called `ws`:

```
Dim nextPosition as double
Dim cObj as ChartObject

If ws.ChartObjects.Count = 0 then
   nextPosition = 1 ' there are no charts, paste the new one one point from the top of the window
Else
   set cObj= ws.ChartObjects(ws.ChartObjects.Count) ' get the most recently added chart...
   ' work out where to move the new chart by summing position & height of the previous chart
   nextPosition = cObj.Top + cObj.Height + 10 ' 10, or whatever padding you want between charts
End if

myChart.Copy
ws.Range("A1").select
ws.Paste

Set cObj= ws.ChartObjects(ws.ChartObjects.Count)
cObj.Top = nextPosition
```

Comment: `ws.Shapes.Count` will include any shapes - charts, images, buttons.  `ws.ChartObjects.Count` will only count charts.

Comment: @Absinthe It may not be the previous chart as the user decides as they are usually 3 different charts they need